# Shorter way to index array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I have a 2D array called `my_array`. To select the 1st, 13th, 14th, 15th, and the 16th element from each row I use the following line

```
desired_elements = my_array[:,[0,12,13,14,15]]
```

This works, but I'm pretty sure that the `[0,12,13,14,15]` part can be written more compactly. I have tried to look for a [way](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_advanced_indexing.htm), but until now I have been unable to do so.

**Question:** Is there a shorter way to write

```
desired_elements = my_array[:,[0,12,13,14,15]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not shorter but equal in length for your specific input, but perhaps it is what you're looking for. You could be using `np.r_`, which **translates slice objects to concatenation along the first axis**.

It's a simple way to build up arrays quickly when you have multiple slices to select.

Here's how you would do with your example:

```
desired_elements = my_array[:, np.r_[0, 12:16]]
```

Now, if you wanted to select more slices, you would probably end up with something shorter than the approach you take, for instance:

```
desired_elements = my_array[:, np.r_[0, 4:8, 11:14]]
```

May I ask why it is so critical to shorten your input?

Comment: Well, imagine if OP wanted to use integers from 12 to 100 ;)